# Connect Four - Negamax AI evaluation function issue

Tags: c++, artificial-intelligence, minimax, negamax

I'm trying to implement NegaMax ai for Connect 4. The algorithm works well some of the time, and the ai can win. However, sometimes it completely fails to block opponent 3 in a rows, or doesn't take a winning shot when it has three in a row.

The evaluation function iterates through the grid (horizontally, vertically, diagonally up, diagonally down), and takes every set of four squares. It then checks within each of these sets and evaluates based on this.

I've based the function on the evaluation code provided here: http://blogs.skicelab.com/maurizio/connect-four.html

My function is as follows:

```
    //All sets of four tiles are evaluated before this
    //and values for the following variables are set.
    if (redFoursInARow != 0)
    {
        redScore = INT_MAX;
    }
    else 
    {
        redScore = (redThreesInARow * threeWeight) + (redTwosInARow * twoWeight);
    }
    int yellowScore = 0;
    if (yellowFoursInARow != 0)
    {
        yellowScore = INT_MAX;
    }
    else
    {
        yellowScore = (yellowThreesInARow * threeWeight) + (yellowTwosInARow * twoWeight);
    }
    int finalScore = yellowScore - redScore;

    return turn ? finalScore : -finalScore; //If this is an ai turn, return finalScore. Else return -finalScore.
```

My negamax function looks like this:

```
    inline int NegaMax(char g[6][7], int depth, int &bestMove, int row, int col, bool aiTurn)
{
    {
        char c = CheckForWinner(g);
        if ('E' != c || 0 == depth)
        {
            return EvaluatePosition(g, aiTurn);
        }
    }
    int bestScore = INT_MIN;

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; ++i)
    {
        if (CanMakeMove(g, i)) //If column i is not full...
        {
            {
                //...then make a move in that column.
                //Grid is a 2d char array.
                //'E' = empty tile, 'Y' = yellow, 'R' = red.
                char newPos[6][7];
                memcpy(newPos, g, sizeof(char) * 6 * 7);
                int newRow = GetNextEmptyInCol(g, i);
                if (aiTurn)
                {
                    UpdateGrid(newPos, i, 'Y');
                }
                else 
                {
                    UpdateGrid(newPos, i, 'R');
                }
                int newScore = 0; int newMove = 0;
                newScore = NegaMax(newPos, depth - 1, newMove, newRow, i, !aiTurn);
                newScore = -newScore;
                if (newScore > bestScore)
                {
                    bestMove = i;
                    bestScore = newScore;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return bestScore;
}
```

I'm aware that connect four has been solved are that there are definitely better ways to go about this, but any help or suggestions with fixing/improving this will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!